# error in passing a value - android

Tags: android

This is the first activity:

```
public static final String level="";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pass);




}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.pass, menu);
    return true;
}


 public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
           i.putExtra("level","2");

        }
```

}
}

This is the second activity:

```
    SeekBar seek_bar;
    Button play_button, pause_button , reapet_button , reapet_button1;
    MediaPlayer player;
    TextView text_shown;
    String s;
    Handler seekHandler = new Handler();

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (null != intent) {
            s = intent.getStringExtra("level");
        }
        getInit();
        seekUpdation();
    }



    public void getInit() {
        seek_bar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek_bar);
        play_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play_button);
        pause_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause_button);
        text_shown = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_shown);
        reapet_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reapet_button);
        reapet_button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reapet_button1);
        play_button.setOnClickListener(this);
        pause_button.setOnClickListener(this);
        reapet_button.setOnClickListener(this);
        reapet_button1.setOnClickListener(this);


        int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("sound"+s, "raw", "com.r");
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId);


        seek_bar.setMax(player.getDuration());

    }

    Runnable run = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            seekUpdation();
        }
    };

    public void seekUpdation() {

        seek_bar.setProgress(player.getCurrentPosition());
        seekHandler.postDelayed(run, 1000);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.play_button:
            text_shown.setText("Playing...");
            player.start();
            break;
        case R.id.reapet_button:
            player.setLooping(true);
                break;
        case R.id.reapet_button1:
            player.setLooping(false);
                break;    
        case R.id.pause_button:
            player.pause();
            text_shown.setText("Paused...");
            break;



        }

    }
}
```

When the user presses the button, I want to pass the value of the string to the other activity but it's not working for me when I run the app. This is the logcat:

```
02-28 21:37:54.979: D/AndroidRuntime(545): Shutting down VM
02-28 21:37:54.979: W/dalvikvm(545): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
02-28 21:37:54.999: E/AndroidRuntime(545): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-28 21:37:54.999: E/AndroidRuntime(545): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rawan/com.rawan.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
02-28 21:37:54.999: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
02-28 21:37:54.999: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
02-28 21:37:54.999: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
02-28 21:37:54.999: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
02-28 21:37:54.999: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-28 21:37:54.999: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-28 21:37:54.999: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-28 21:37:54.999: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-28 21:37:54.999: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-28 21:37:54.999: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-28 21:37:54.999: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-28 21:37:54.999: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-28 21:37:54.999: E/AndroidRuntime(545): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
02-28 21:37:54.999: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:892)
02-28 21:37:54.999: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResourceFd(Resources.java:854)
02-28 21:37:54.999: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:641)
02-28 21:37:54.999: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at com.rawan.MainActivity.getInit(MainActivity.java:66)
02-28 21:37:54.999: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at com.rawan.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
02-28 21:37:54.999: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-28 21:37:54.999: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
02-28 21:37:54.999: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  ... 11 more
02-28 22:23:31.238: W/ResourceType(603): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
02-28 22:23:31.238: D/AndroidRuntime(603): Shutting down VM
02-28 22:23:31.248: W/dalvikvm(603): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
02-28 22:23:31.269: E/AndroidRuntime(603): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-28 22:23:31.269: E/AndroidRuntime(603): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rawan/com.rawan.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
02-28 22:23:31.269: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
02-28 22:23:31.269: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
02-28 22:23:31.269: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
02-28 22:23:31.269: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
02-28 22:23:31.269: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-28 22:23:31.269: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-28 22:23:31.269: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-28 22:23:31.269: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-28 22:23:31.269: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-28 22:23:31.269: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-28 22:23:31.269: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-28 22:23:31.269: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-28 22:23:31.269: E/AndroidRuntime(603): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
02-28 22:23:31.269: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:892)
02-28 22:23:31.269: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResourceFd(Resources.java:854)
02-28 22:23:31.269: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:641)
02-28 22:23:31.269: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at com.rawan.MainActivity.getInit(MainActivity.java:60)
02-28 22:23:31.269: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at com.rawan.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
02-28 22:23:31.269: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-28 22:23:31.269: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
02-28 22:23:31.269: E/AndroidRuntime(603):  ... 11 more
02-28 22:27:18.398: W/ResourceType(632): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
02-28 22:27:18.408: D/AndroidRuntime(632): Shutting down VM
02-28 22:27:18.408: W/dalvikvm(632): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
02-28 22:27:18.428: E/AndroidRuntime(632): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-28 22:27:18.428: E/AndroidRuntime(632): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rawan/com.rawan.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
02-28 22:27:18.428: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
02-28 22:27:18.428: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
02-28 22:27:18.428: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
02-28 22:27:18.428: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
02-28 22:27:18.428: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-28 22:27:18.428: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-28 22:27:18.428: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-28 22:27:18.428: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-28 22:27:18.428: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-28 22:27:18.428: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-28 22:27:18.428: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-28 22:27:18.428: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-28 22:27:18.428: E/AndroidRuntime(632): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
02-28 22:27:18.428: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:892)
02-28 22:27:18.428: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResourceFd(Resources.java:854)
02-28 22:27:18.428: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:641)
02-28 22:27:18.428: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at com.rawan.MainActivity.getInit(MainActivity.java:59)
02-28 22:27:18.428: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at com.rawan.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
02-28 22:27:18.428: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-28 22:27:18.428: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
02-28 22:27:18.428: E/AndroidRuntime(632):  ... 11 more
02-28 22:32:18.473: I/Process(632): Sending signal. PID: 632 SIG: 9
```

Comment: You should include the logcat output. Also, have you declared second activity in your manifest?

Comment: I want to see this red logcat ;-)

Comment: I add it , and the second activity is declared

  <activity
            android:name="com.rawan.Pass"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_pass" >
        </activity>

Comment: include your xml files. And specify which of your Activities is the MainActivity as well.Seems the trouble is where your instance your MediaPlayer. My guess would be your buttons aren't really named reapet_button and reapet_button1

Comment: yes I specify the "pass" as main activity in mainfest .. no the problem with the intent because i tried the app before I add the part of pass a value and it was worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is with the text being set,

Have you tried to convert the text to String by using any of these methods, I am not sure if it will solve your problem or not but you should try it

```
   i.putExtra("level",""+2);
```

or

```
i.putExtra("level","2".toString());
```

start activity afterwords as shown below

```
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: YES!! this solve the problems appears but the action of the button not directed me to other activity.

Comment: you have to start activity by using this code..

startActivity(i);

Comment: Yes I did it but it's not moving to the other activity.

Comment: did you set the onclicklisteners on the respective button because there's no code in your oncreate method or if you have implemented the listener. i could help you more if you can upload your code at bitbucket or mail it to me at ravinder_bhandari@yahoo.com

Comment: i have made the changes its wokring now.. have mailed it to you

Answer (score 1):

Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0

try this

```
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("sound"+s, "raw", this.getPackageName());
```

Answer (score 0):

The Java code is not able to find something specified in your XML.

Comment: like what ? can u explain more .. I'm beginner in android development